# silverlight animation help

Tags: silverlight

I am very new to silverlight animation. I want to programmatically create an animation, like a slide show. I have an image control initially loaded with an image, should scroll fast from right to center of the screen, stay there for 3 seconds then move slowly towards left and disappear off the screen.

Then again should appear from right to center with a new image, and so on, and forever. The image is randomly fetched from wcf service, which works fine.

Here is my funky code, I played with it. I really don't know where to begin.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard1.Completed += new EventHandler(Storyboard1_Completed);

    DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
    da.To = 100;
    da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath(Image.VisibilityProperty));
    Storyboard.SetTarget(da, image1);

    Storyboard1.Begin();
}
```

I couldn't find a good tutorial on silverlight animation either. Everything I looked at wasn't clear, it's confusing. I prefer doing it in code so that I will have better control than xaml.

Comment: Hey gangt. Could you be a bit more specific about your question please? What is it you want, tutorials on animation, or help with how to achieve what you described, etc.?

Comment: I need help to create the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice tutorial on silverlight using expression blend. My focus was on the animation part.

[Silverlight Animation Tutorial plus sample code](http://www.kirupa.com/blend_silverlight/easing_sl_wpf_pg1.htm)

This is exactly what I was looking for.